# custom key on array in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have an array of numbers like

```
const arr:number[] = [0,12,14,18,24,36]
```

that I want to assign custom keys to

```
arr.foo = 126
```

However, when I do this typescript tells me `Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'number[]'`

How should I type my Array to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create an interface to solve this

```
interface MyType<T> extends Array<T> {
    foo ?:number
}

const arr:MyType<number>= [0,12,14,18,24,36];

arr.foo = 12
```